# I want to change the background color of a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want to change the background color of this Flutter application.

Please let me know how to add a picture as background.
And how to change the opacity of that image?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Loginscreen());

class Loginscreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/login';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          //title: Text('LOG IN'),
          elevation: 0,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black54),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    hintText: 'User Name',
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black54),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    hintText: 'Password',
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: null,
                  child: Text(
                    'Log In',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                  shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is my solution working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the background color in your `Scaffold`

For example

```
Scaffold(
   backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
   appBar: AppBar(),
)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy.. please be kind enough for the other part also. :-)

Answer (score 0):

## Change background color

Depends on the root, you can use for example:

- `backgroundColor` when `Scaffold` is parent
- `color` when `Container` is parent

So

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
);
```

or

```
Container(
  color: Colors.blueAccent,
);
```

depends where you need background color.

## Set image as background

To add "something" as background you have to wrap it in to [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) (which has list of childrens like `Column` or `Row`)

> This class is useful if you want to overlap several children in a simple way, for example having some text and an image, overlaid with a gradient and a button attached to the bottom.

Change from:

```
Container(
    child: Text("Example text"),
),
```

to:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Image.asset("assets/background_image.jpg"),
    Container(
      child: Text("Example text"),
    ),
  ],
),
```

## Set opacity of the widget

When you need to change opacity for example this view:

```
Image.asset("assets/background_image.jpg")
```

you have to wrap it with `Opacity` widget:

```
Opacity(
  opacity: 0.5,
  child: Image.asset("assets/background_image.jpg"),
),
```

And set `opacity` which is range from 0.0 to 1.0, where:

> An opacity of 1.0 is fully opaque (100% visibility)
>
> An opacity of 0.5 is half opaque (50% visibility)
>
> An opacity of 0.0 is fully transparent (0% visibility = NOT visible)

## Full example

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Opacity(
      opacity: 0.5,
      child: Image.asset("assets/background_image.jpg"),
    ),
    Container(
      child: Text("Example text"),
    ),
  ],
),
```